# parse CSV file in PHP by column

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I want to open CSV (comma separated value) file in PHP by column, i want to take all datas from 3 columns. I tried with this code, but this only shows me data by row:

```
  $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("ut.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
      }
      fclose($handle);
    }
```

How i can take all datas from one column ?

EXAMPLE:
This i my file in Excel, which is exported to SCV:
http://prntscr.com/mzcfcw

I want to take in php values from colum Name and Price and find duplicate values in  column Name, compare their prices.

Comment: Can you show a sample input (a few rows) and the output you want from that?

Comment: @NigelRen I added

Comment: You should have a look at `array_count_values` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: @kuh-chan problem is how i can take values from excel by column

Comment: It's not an excel file. It's a CSV (comma separated value) file.

Comment: @yunzen yes that is correct

Comment: I changed the tile, content and tags.

Comment: Could you insert the first few lines of the CSV file into your question?

Comment: Seems you just copied and pasted the example #1 from the [PHP documentation of fgetcsv](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Comment: Did you check this community example? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#43296

Comment: @yunzen i will check that example right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fgetcsv** parses the given handle line by line (rows). It isn't possible to parse a csv file by column using core php. However, if you know the position of the 3 columns for which you wish to access the values, you could simply ignore all other columns:

```
 //position (zero indexed) of required columns
 $columnsToProcess=[0,3,4]
 for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
 //do something with value if column's index is in the required columns array 
            if(in_array($c,$columnsToProcess)){
                //value at position $c equals $data[$c]
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
             }          
        }
```

Moe info about fgetcsv : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php